# Python Django + Z3 Segmentation fault

Tags: python, django, segmentation-fault, z3, z3py

I am trying to build a Django web application using Python 3.4.3 and Anaconda virtual environments.

The application involves using ANTLR and the Z3 proof checker.

I am getting a segmentation fault error deterministically (every run) somewhere in the Z3 code (discovered this by having prints in the code). The errors occur for any input given **when sending the requests via the Django web server**. Everything works fine if I just run the ANTLR + Z3 function I am interested in with the same input.

Also, the seg faults occur after one commit which seems to not affect the file in question in any way.

Relevant files presented below:

```
# Types.py
import uuid
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/username/project_name/theorem_prover')

from rest_framework import serializers

from app.api.models.Proof import Proof
from django.db import models

from Z3TypeBuilder import Z3TypeBuilder


class Type(models.Model):
    proofId = models.ForeignKey(Proof)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    @classmethod
        def is_valid(cls, types):
        type_builder = Z3TypeBuilder(dict(), dict())
        valid = type_builder.visitInputArray(types)
        return valid

    @classmethod
    def get_maps(cls, types):
        param_map = dict()
        predicate_map = dict()
        type_builder = Z3TypeBuilder(param_map, predicate_map)
        valid = type_builder.visitInputArray(types)
        return valid, param_map, predicate_map


    class TypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Type
            fields = ('id', 'proofId', 'text')
```

The one above is the file representing the model for Types

```
import logging

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication

from app.api.models.Types import Type, TypeSerializer

from app.api.csrf import CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication
from app.api.utils import Z3Exception

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@authentication_classes((CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
class TypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Type.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TypeSerializer

    @csrf_exempt
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = TypeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            prev_query = Type.objects.filter(proofId=request.data['proofId'])
            types = [t['text'] for t in TypeSerializer(prev_query, many=True).data]
            types.append(serializer.validated_data['text'])
            if Type.is_valid(types):
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                #TODO
                raise Z3Exception('Syntax Error', 'text', status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def list(self, request):
        query = Type.objects.filter(proofId=request.query_params['proofId'])
        serializer = TypeSerializer(query, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And here is the ANTLR + Z3 file where things crash:

```
import sys
from antlr4 import *

from error.folTypeSyntaxErrorListener import folTypeSyntaxErrorListener
from folTypeLexer import folTypeLexer
from folTypeParser import folTypeParser
from folTypeVisitor import folTypeVisitor
from z3 import *

 class Z3TypeBuilder(folTypeVisitor):

    def __init__(self, param_map, predicate_map):

        # from user's type to z3 type sort
        self.__type_map = dict()

        # from user's predicate type to z3 function
        self.predicate_map = predicate_map

        # predicate tuple's arguments' z3 type sorts
        self.param_map = param_map

    # Visit a parse tree produced by folTypeParser#init.
    def visitInit(self, ctx: folTypeParser.InitContext):
        for d in ctx.declaration():
            self.visit(d)

    # Visit a parse tree produced by folTypeParser#declaration.
    def visitDeclaration(self, ctx: folTypeParser.DeclarationContext):
        #print("visitDeclaration")
        declaration = self.predicate_map.get(ctx.PREPOSITION().getText())
        if declaration is None:
            children = self.visit(ctx.predicateType())
            self.param_map[ctx.PREPOSITION().getText()] = children
            # append BoolSort() after putting in param_map
            children.append(BoolSort())
            # print(children)
            declaration = Function(ctx.PREPOSITION().getText(), *children)
            self.predicate_map[ctx.PREPOSITION().getText()] = declaration
        return declaration

    # Visit a parse tree produced by folTypeParser#predicateType.
    def visitPredicateType(self, ctx: folTypeParser.PredicateTypeContext):
        print("visitPredicateType")
        return list(map((lambda s: self.visit(s)), ctx.sort()))

    # Visit a parse tree produced by folTypeParser#sort.
    def visitSort(self, ctx: folTypeParser.SortContext):
        print("visitSort")
        if ctx.INT():
            return IntSort()
        elif ctx.BOOL():
            return BoolSort()
        else:
            type = self.__type_map.get(ctx.TYPE().getText()[1:])
            if type is None:
                myVarThatWorks = ctx.TYPE().getText()[1:]
                print("HERE IS MY VAR")
                print(myVarThatWorks)
                type = DeclareSort(myVarThatWorks)
                print("I WILL NEVER GET HERE")
                self.__type_map[ctx.TYPE().getText()[1:]] = type
            return type

    def visitInputArray(self, array):
        for i in array:
            input = InputStream(i)
            lexer = folTypeLexer(input)
            stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
            parser = folTypeParser(stream)
            errorListener = folTypeSyntaxErrorListener()
            parser.removeErrorListeners()
            parser.addErrorListener(errorListener)

            # Generate Parse tree and check for syntax errors
            tree = parser.init()
            if not errorListener.isGood():
                return False

            self.visit(tree)
        return True

    def visitInputFile(self, file):
        lexer = folTypeLexer(file)
        stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        parser = folTypeParser(stream)

        tree = parser.init()
        self.visit(tree)

def main(argv):
    type_builder = Z3TypeBuilder()
    type_builder.visitInputFile(FileStream(argv[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

And now the fun thing is that if you check the git diff in the picture (that's the diff in between the last commit and the commit that works, none of the files which might seem relevant is affected (the whole thing dies upon a post request to create a new type).

[image: Diff 1]
[image: Diff 2]

The other changes in that commit are all related to frontend. I tried to investigate and I could find nothing that could in any way cause the failure. Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

Thank you!

IMPORTANT LATER EDIT: The error disappeared once z3types was no longer imported in `ToShowViewSet.py`

Finding the cause would be great!